# JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK : Unable to start google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, netbeans

I get the following errors when i try to run a sample project in netbeans on google app server. The server doesn't start up. How can i resolve these errors if they exist ? I am using netbeans 7.1

```
BUILD FAILED
W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\Guestbook\nbproject\build-impl.xml:550: The following error occurred while executing this line:
W:\UnderTest\NetbeansCurrent\Guestbook\nbproject\build-impl.xml:300: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

Comment: just re-name your jre directory for a minute and try again.

Comment: Did you note that it says JAVA_HOME is pointed to a Java Runtime Environment (JRE), not a Java Development Kit (JDK)?

Comment: >>> JAVA_HOME must point to JDK home, not JRE

Comment: you might need to point to JDK. Because, JDK is for development, it includes compiler. JRE does not have a compiler. If you dont have JDK, install it.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi you've reformatted, but i think _"Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"_ is part of the output

Comment: _i have been running my projects from command prompt for some time. and it never gave me a problem even with netbeans_

Comment: @OpDeCirkel That's not an output. Its a command line error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install jdk and set JAVA_HOME in environments variables to path that you jdk was installed. Currently it points to jre.

Comment: [is that ok](http://i49.tinypic.com/14t7seh.jpg). But i have been developing and compiling my java apps from netbeans and also from command prompt.I never got a problem

Comment: yes, should be ok. Some application does not nead jdk, jre also contains javac and java to compile and run your application. But gae neads.

Answer (score 0):

probable solution will be hear : [setting jdk path in netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html)
or , if you setting JAVA_HOME in windows env then use %JAVA_HOME%