# IntelliJ - Can't start - "JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For every other StackOverflow question that's been asked about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780283/java-home-does-not-point-to-the-jdk-unable-to-start-google-app-engine), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124368/gradle-doesnt-work-in-intellij-problems-with-java-home), and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=959556), I've followed all the steps to resolve this issue, and none have worked.

When launching IntelliJ IDEA 64-bit on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine, I encounter the following error:

```
The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74") 
does not point to a valid JVM installation.
```

[image: Error launching IDEA]

However, the file path does exist:

[image: Filepath screenshot]

And in my Environment Variables, I have set `JAVA_HOME` to that location:

[image: Environment Variables]

I've tinkered around with putting it in my User variables instead of the System and vice-versa, and tried putting it in both. It didn't work with the Java 7 JDK I had originally, so I just downloaded the Java 8 JDK and tried it - no dice.

I also restarted my computer, and CMD can use `java` and `javac` with no problem at all:

[image]

Any help on how I could resolve this? My last resort is uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ, which I may have to do.

Comment: try removing the double inverted comma in the path

Comment: Make sure to start using **webstorm64.exe** instead of **webstorm.exe**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `java` and `javac` executables are using the `PATH` environment variable, while intelliJ is using `JAVA_HOME` variable. Remove the additional quotation marks in your `JAVA_HOME` value.

It might shows that your path to the jdk installation directory is hard coded in the `PATH`, rather then using `%JAVA_HOME%`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the quotes would cause such a hassle, since in CMD it wants you to surround a file path with spaces in it with quotes. This did fix it - thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the issue was that `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to a path upto /bin folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\`) - while Eclipse accepts this, IntelliJ does not.

Updating to `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91` resolved the issue.

Comment: Intermediate spaces DOESN'T AFFECT, at least in Windows 7.

Comment: you saved my day ... same issue with Pycharm installation

Answer (score 3):

The problem will almost certainly be with the quotation marks around your JAVA_HOME path. Remove those and see if it works. If not, then I would recommend only putting your JDK installations under the root and with no spaces in them. I tend to put them in `C:\JDK\1.8.0_65`, etc. It makes referencing them far easier and you don't have to worry about quotation marks to protect spaces like you do with "Program Files".

Comment: Yeah, I hate that Windows allows spaces in file paths. In Linux it's much easier to not have those, and underscores would work better than spaces.

Comment: @homersimpson Agreed. Hate spaces in file paths. Even on Windows, I don't use them where I can avoid it. Saves so much trouble and makes writing scripts/code far less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.. My mistake was I was taking the path till /bin/ and putting ; at last.

Correct is - JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92

no /bin/ no ';'

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issues opening PHPSTORM from command line.
Solution was to download jdk version 8 x86(32bit). Edit settings in Environment Variables by setting JAVA_HOME path in user variables for... to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_221

Answer (score 0):

Open a CMD window, and enter:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Verify the result is indeed the path entered your `JAVA_HOME` variable,
i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74`.

In my case, a space was slipped in, that was not visible in the 
Envrironment Variables window.

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME` for me

Answer (score 0):

My problem was adding 2 path in JAVA_HOME variable (I had added x64 jdk path with x86 jdk and my android studio needed just the x86 one. I deleted the x64 path and it has just worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had seemed to be due to attempting to launch idea.exe rather than idea64.exe - when I moved to the 64 one then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question appeared in my google search, and none of the aforementioned answers worked for me - here is my resolution.

What worked for me was changing `\` to `/` in path.

So in my case it was:
`C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.11/` :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also change the installation of OpenJDK (if you still have the installer packages) and add the JAVA_HOME variable (you have to enable it), afterwards just click through the installation until it is finished.