# Error Launching IntelliJ--does not point to a valid JVM

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have declared JAVA_HOME in environment variables and I have the following value in PATH: C:\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin;%JAVA_HOME%;
But still while launching IntelliJ I am getting below error.

[image]

The values from command prompt:

[image]

PS: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159433/intellij-cant-start-java-home-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jvm-installation) is a different problem. But the one I am facing does not have any such issue.
I have JRE in my  path variable and JDK in JAVA_HOME.(attached the screenshots)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio error: "Environment variable does not point to a valid JVM instalation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185358/android-studio-error-environment-variable-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jvm-instal)

Comment: Modern versions of IntelliJ come with their own supported JVM which "just works".

Comment: I have uninstalled and installed the latets version of IntelliJ again. But still it is still the same

Answer (score 3):

Your `%JAVA_HOME%` variable should point to the directory of Java installation. Here's what you can do to fix it.

1. Set `%JAVA_HOME%` to `C:\Java\jre1.8.0_45\`
2. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `%PATH%` variable

Comment: It didnt work for me. The above error is also not coming now. No response after launching IntelliJ after doing the above changes

Comment: Intellij might startup slowly. Can you check if there is `idea` or `intellij` process running?

Comment: A JRE will not be enough.  IntelliJ uses javac from the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add JDK to your system variables and point it to the JRE folder (do not point it to BIN folder)