# how do i handle Error Launching (PhpStorm) in filezilla

Tags: filezilla, phpstorm-2019

[image: I want to edit my files in filezilla but i faced to this error]

how could i handle this problem ...I am really confused

Comment: [JAVA_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36159433/205233)

Comment: it is not my problem he used doubleqout but i dont

Comment: Well you did not mention that in your post - just posting a screenshot of an error message doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ - Can't start - "JAVA\_HOME does not point to a valid JVM installation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159433/intellij-cant-start-java-home-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jvm-installation)

Answer (score 1):

Your `JAVA_HOME` path should only point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231`, and not to some subdirectory or `.dll` file in that directory.